# Can CodeIgniter be used on an RPi?

Tags: web-server, php

Can I use a Raspberry Pi as a web server for a [CodeIgniter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter) app? I can't find anything online. I saw tutorials on installing Wordpress but no CodeIgniter...

Comment: what did you find on the web?

Comment: Off course you can, cause' I think for small project you can RPi as web app using codeigniter. Here this [link](https://github.com/simonrenger/kitchenhelper/wiki/Setup-on-a-RASPBERRY-PI) for giving you step by step for building web server using CI. Hope this help.

Comment: @MuhammadAndykMaulana, following the link you provided, the KitchenHelper app seem to be unknown even for google?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question about an *operating system*, not a *brand of device*, although the conflation/confusion is a common one.  Point being, the answer depends mostly on what operating system you want to use.

The most widely used operating system on the Pi platform is Raspbian, a [GNU/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) distribution.  You will find lots of references online to the "LAMP" stack, which refers to a common MVC implementation where LAM is for "linux apache mysql" and the p is alternately for python, perl, or PHP.  If you can use CodeIgniter with the Apache server, you should be able to use it on linux therefore on a Raspbian powered Pi. There are other choices of web server as well that should work in this scenario.

At a glance I think CodeIgniter is written entirely in PHP, so you should not have to compile anything from C unless it has dependent modules requiring such that aren't available directly through the Raspbian repos, in which case you'll have to build them, which is not impossible.

To check for modules available directly through Raspbian use `apt search [module name] | grep "^php"`, e.g.,

```
apt search xml | grep "^php"
```

I believe PHP has its own package manager, `pecl`, which can also be used and should take care of building things if that is necessary.  Always rely on the distro package manager (`apt`) first; sometimes you may need a more recent version of something, which `pecl` should be able to get.  It is fine to install a package with both in this case, meaning, you don't have to remove the one from `apt` if you install it then realize you need one from `pecl`, because the latter should take precedence.

If you are looking for more information, **don't include "Raspberry Pi" in your search terms** when something more general is more appropriate (such as "linux" or "apache").

Comment: I installed Raspbian Stretch, LAMP, MySQL, Php, PhpMyadmin. I think it's possible since Wordpress can be installed, I just dont know how.

Comment: Have you tried searching "codeigniter lamp"?  I seem to see a lot of stuff there.  It doesn't matter that it isn't for the Pi.  Linux distros differ in trivial ways from one another (such as configuration paths), so if you find a tutorial using Debian that's the most similar to Raspbian.  Otherwise Ubuntu or anything.